# EC2 instance's disk usage is filling up rapidly,

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an ec2 instance.
suddenly it's disk 100% use.I remove 10GB of my syslog but with in 9 hours my disk again full and syslog again goes 10GB and disk 100% use.

Comment: You can stop the EC2 instance, it will stop generating logs. <Guys Forgive me. I couldn't resist.>

Comment: @Monand Wizard You should check which program is generating the log and then you should 'log rotate' to manage log lifecycle.

Comment: I change my system log rotation to 3.
and all of my service have their own log directory to server their own log

Comment: You might receive a better response at: https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

What could be the cause:

- Applications or services running on the instance are generating excessive logs.
- Abnormal or repetitive log messages that might be causing the rapid growth.

What you could do:

- Compress older logs to save disk space without losing data.
- Regularly clean up temporary files and other unnecessary data to free up disk space.

Comment: can you suggest any automation process or any shell script that complete your suggestion by schedule .